# grab brush? on UV editor change radius Blender 2.8

Tags: uv

How do you change the radius of the brush in the UV editor for grabbing UVs.  All I've found is **F** and **Shift-F** but, it doesn't change the UV brush radius.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered my own question. You tap the **F** key or, hold **Shift** and tap **F**.

This may seem really obvious but, I am coming from using the brush in Autodesk Mudbox where the keys are **B** and **M** and you just hold them down.